# Creating dynamic Query using SqlBuilder in java

Tags: java, sql, sqlbuilder

can you help me for creating sql query in where condition

```
SELECT * FROM classicmodels.offices t1 INNER JOIN classicmodels.employees t0 
  ON (t1.officeCode = t0.officeCode) INNER JOIN classicmodels.customers t2 ON 
  ( (t0.employeeNumber = t2.salesRepEmployeeNumber) OR (t0.firstName = 
  t2.contactFirstName) ) WHERE (t2.creditLimit > 70000) AND (t2.creditLimit < 
  100000) OR (t0.officeCode = 6)
ORDER BY
t0.firstName ASC
```

I am not able to create please tell me how to create AND or OR both condition in single query

```
WHERE (t2.creditLimit > 70000) AND (t2.creditLimit < 100000) OR (t0.officeCode = 6)
```

How can create dynamic query may more then one time AND condition or may be more then one time OR condition. it's condition comes random. then i want to create query. can you help me....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if "SqlBuilder" is a specific library, because there are several libraries that have a `SqlBuilder` class (e.g. [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/reference/org/apache/ibatis/jdbc/SqlBuilder.html)), and there are other libraries that *are* SQL builders (e.g. [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org)). So, I'm just going to answer this for jOOQ (I work for the vendor).

#### Using jOOQ

Your query could be written as such, assuming you're using the code generator:

```java
// Aliasing is not necessary in your case, but here it is, still:
Offices t1 = OFFICES.as("t1");
Employees t0 = EMPLOYEES.as("t0");
Customers t2 = CUSTOMERS.as("t2");

Result<?> result =
ctx.select()
   .from(t1)
   .join(t0).on(t1.OFFICECODE.eq(t0.OFFICECODE))
   .join(t2).on(t0.EMPLOYEENUMBER.eq(t2.SALESREPEMPLOYEENUMBER)
            .or(t0.FIRSTNAME.eq(t2.CONTACTFIRSTNAME)))
   .where(t2.CREDITLIMIT.gt(70000))
   .and(t2.CREDITLIMIT.lt(100000))
   .or(t0.OFFICECODE.eq(6))
   .orderBy(t0.FIRSTNAME)
   .fetch();
```

#### Using some other, specific SqlBuilder

If your *specific SqlBuilder* cannot handle the type of predicate you've written, perhaps you can rewrite it as such:

```sql
WHERE (t2.creditLimit BETWEEN 70001 AND 99999) OR (t0.officeCode = 6)
```